# What is the min relay min fee code -26?

Tags: sendrawtransaction

What is this code ?

66 : min relay fee not met  ( code - 26 )

I received this code after trying to send my
rawtransaction.

Answer (score 7):

It seems that the fee provided by you is too low and it's total amount is lower than relay fee (==the minimum fee amount that can guarantee that your transaction would be retranslated to the net). You can find this amount by calling **getinfo** function and taking **"relayfee"**. Currently "relayfee" is 0.00001000 at BTC Mainnet.

Comment: The method is now named `-getinfo` in Bitcoin Core v26.0.