# Do I have a chance to commit a transaction without any network fee?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, transaction-fees, network, protocol

I know how transaction fees are calculated. Also I understand that a transaction with a higher fee will be approved much faster than a transaction with the lowest one.

**Does the bitcoin protocol allow committing a transaction without paying a fee (even if the transaction will be approved within 2 or 3 weeks)?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The protocol allows it but I believe many nodes will not relay a transaction whose fee is below a configured threshold.

See

- [What is the min relay min fee code -26?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/69282/13866)

Answer (score 0):

The default `minRelayTxFeeRate` is 1,000 sat/kvB. Nodes using the default value will not relay transactions that pay a smaller feerate than that. I just did a search for confirmed transactions paying less than the `minRelayTxFeeRate` ([feerates up to 0.00000249 BTC/kWU, excluding coinbase txs](https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/transactions?s=block_id(desc)&q=is_coinbase(false),fee_per_kwu(..249)#f=hash,block_id,time,is_coinbase,fee_per_kwu,fee_per_kwu_usd)): [image]

Lately, most days there are a couple and never more than a handful. Given that there are over 62 blocks worth of transactions tracked on mempool explorers offering feerates below the `minRelayTxFeeRate`, it's safe to assume that those few transactions were created by the corresponding miner themself and included in their own block, and there is no miner that includes below `minRelayTxFeeRate` transactions from the mempool without out-of-band encouragement (or there would be a lot more). [image]

I would not expect any transaction paying less than `minRelayTxFeeRate` to get organically confirmed even when blocks are not full otherwise.

Answer (score -3):

Yes you have, fee is optional. When the mempool clears some miner will likely mine your transaction

Comment: These days most nodes on the network, and miners, will not accept or forward a transaction with a fee below the minrelayfee (which for recent Bitcoin Core versions is 1 sat/vbyte by default). Perhaps if you send it to a miner directly, they may include it, but even that is unlikely without adding some incentive (in the form of a fee...).